# Cannot install PyQt6 in python 3.9. error: metadata-generation-failed and error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, pip, pyqt, pyqt6

This is a new raspberry pi environment with default python 3.9.2. The pip version is 22.0.4. I can install pyqt5, but my project requires pyqt6.
There are two errors always occur:  'error: metadata-generation-failed' and 'error: subprocess-exited-with-error'.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip --version
pythonpip 22.0.4 from /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install pyqt6
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting pyqt6
  Using cached PyQt6-6.2.3.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [29 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5inxj2op/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5inxj2op/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5inxj2op/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 594, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "project.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5inxj2op/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5inxj2op/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 241, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5inxj2op/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a fix but maybe a solution for someone who want to use pyqt6 on Raspberry Pi:**

I tried for hours and hours to install PyQt6 on my Raspberry Pi because i developed an application in a virtual machine and wanted to use it on a RP4. I tried with Raspberry Pi OS, Ubuntu 22.10 and PopOS with Python 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11 (in venv), but everytime when i used pip install pyqt6 i got this error "**metadata generation failed**". I installed all the dependecies and side-packages (at least i assume) - nothing worked.

At this point i was sure it had something to do with the architecture (aarch64), but on the other hand i had read that people got it running on RP... Then i discovered that there is a package for Arch-Linux "https://archlinuxarm.org/packages/aarch64/python-pyqt6". I gave it a try.

Flashed my RP4 again and installed **Manjaro ARM Gnome 22.12** from Raspberry Pi Imager (v1.7.3).

PyQt5 was already pre installed which made me confident. I installed "**python-pyqt6**" from the Package Manager and checked optional pyqt6-tools. There are a lot of dependencies which are installed automatically. On first use the Package manager will propably update a lot of packages. This will take a while. PyQt6 will install at the end.

I also had to unset the environment variable **QT_QPA_PLATFORM**. But then , finally , my pyqt6-application was running on Raspberry PI.

I am currently using Python 3.10.9